# Samsung Galaxy s2 stuck on boot screen after an OTA upgrade

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, boot, reboot, device-firmware

I upgraded firmware on my Samsung Galaxy SII via OTA. My starting firmware was android 2.3.4 (gingerbread) and after two successful updates it was on android 2.3.6 . Now it prompted me for another upgrade (12.1 MB or so). I downloaded it (successfully), it installed successfully  but when the phone reboot, it got stuck on the booting screen which displays 'Samsung Galaxy SII' and the model no. I9100G . I tired:
1. Reboot
2. Hard Reset

But it still won't budge. When I connect my charger (phone turned off), the battery symbol shows up, and since it is going into recovery mode, I know all is not lost. So what is the problem? More importantly, how do I solve it? SOS.

Comment: Something happen.  The OTA failed.  You are pretty much limited to your choices.  Your provider might be able to help...but all they can do is reflash it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you flashed the phone before and do you have any new boot loaders on it? What kind of recovery mode is it booting into? [ClockworkMod](http://www.techcredo.com/android/how-to-boot-the-samsung-galaxy-s2-into-recovery-mode)? Or does Samsung have its own recovery?

If possible I would suggest maybe downloading the correct ROM for your handset from cyanogenMod and putting it on your SD card then try flashing that on. Do a clean wipe and then set up your Google account again so you have all the numbers on phone again.

On my phone I have installed clockwork mod and new boot loader so I can flash the phone again if the ROM ever gets broken. Obviously i don't know exactly how your phone is set up so i wouldn't be able to give exact instructions on how to do it.

***EDIT: I would suggest flashing a ROM onto it from recovery if its not booting then what you have in the mobile world is probably a "brick". Dont see many other optuions to be honest.***

Bill

Comment: Nope,in OTA, you don't need to flash the device and Samsung has its own recovery. I am going to flash the ROM manually as the last resort, but was looking for better alternatives.

Comment: I know with the OTA you don't need to root. But if its not booting then I don't see many other choices to be honest.

Comment: You don't need root to flash anything if you get into recovery.  Just download the stock firmware and flash it with odin.

Comment: That's what I am planning to do

Comment: this is why samsung uses kies. their firmware has caused issues in just about every OTA. My first OTA put my phone in soft-brick, I had to odin to stock.